# DIsplayPort monitors not detected after windows powers them off

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I'm running dual monitors off a RTX 3070, both over DP. I have my power settings to turn off the monitors after 15 minutes and put the computer to sleep after 60 minutes. If I leave the computer for 20 minutes and come back both monitors will be powered off and the PC will still be on. If I move the mouse or press a key on the keyboard one or both of the monitors (whether it's one or both seems to be random) will remain off and undetected. If I let the computer go to sleep and wake it up the monitors seem to be detected just fine, it's only when Windows turns off the monitors.

Turning the monitors on and off has no effect. I found that if I unplug one of the DP cables and plug it back in that monitor will work. Once one of the monitors was working again I checked the event log to see if there was any obvious errors and didn't find any.

I've tried disabling DDC/CI on the monitors and I've turned off FreeSync as some places have mentioned that might be the problem. I don't have any other DP monitors I can use to see if it's the monitors specifically.

What could be the cause of this?

**Specs**

- Windows 10 Pro (Build 19042)
- AMD Ryzen 7 3700X
- GeForce RTX 3070 (Driver 457.51)
- AOC 24G2E5 Monitors

Comment: This is often a timing/race condition. The displays don't wake fast enough for the computer to recognise them. I don't know a cure, but the workaround is often to wake the displays manually before the computer.

Comment: That makes sense if the PC is in sleep mode but this only happens when the PC **isn't** in sleep mode

Comment: Did you try it to see?

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean something else by wake them but I've tried power cycling the monitors when they're in this state. The PC doesn't even recognize that they are connected, it's as if when Windows turns off the displays they're disconnecting from the PC

Comment: I didn't mean power-cycle. Is there not some button on the display itself that will act to wake it?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a wake button. This is a very irritating "feature" on these monitors, you can't even access the menu when they are in their power saving mode